# How do I not repeat the name of a generic data type when using it?

Tags: c#, .net

```
public class MyPath {
    protected static Dictionary<string, object> Cache;
    void MyPath() {
        if (Cache.Count == 0) {
            var jspath = "path.json";
            // The code below repeats the type name:
            Cache = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(File.ReadAllText(jspath)));
            ...
```

So, how can I fetch the type from the static class member rather than repeating myself when I'm deserializing the object by writing Dictionary?

Comment: I'm not sure I see the issue here. Where is the code getting repeated?

Comment: The definition of "Dictionary<string, object>" is repeated in the DeserializeObject call and in the name of the variable. I want to fetch the type from the static class member rather than repeating it.

Comment: It's not really violation of DRY, as much as using "int" in multiple places would be. You can use aliases, or create your own class, and use it there.

Comment: How is that violating DRY? It's a class name declaration.

Comment: The only improvement that I see that could be made (and this is grasping at straws), is declaring `Cache` as `IDictionary<string, object>`. This doesn't violate DRY

Comment: @user407896 you're not actually repeating code, you're going to have the  types duplicated all over.

Comment: It does not make sense that this question got put on hold as "unclear what you are asking", because it is perfectly clear what OP wants to achieve. Perhaps he misnamed it as DRY, but the question is easy to understand. I am voting to reopen it.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to avoid repeating the type name, you can write a static generic method that captures the type of `Cache`:

```
private static void ReadFromJson<T>(ref T cache, string jspath) {
    cache = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(File.ReadAllText(jspath)));
}
```

You can use this method as follows:

```
if (Cache.Count == 0) {
    var jspath = "path.json";
    ReadFromJson(ref Cache, jspath);
    ...
```